# How to get max _id from elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I have created a river which will run every hour to fetch data from DB(Using jdbc river plugin).

```
select * from orders
```

Instead of selecting all records i want to select data which are appended based on primary key.Query would be :

```
select * from orders where deviceid > '(Max Id in Elastic search)'
```

How can i get max _id from elastic search?

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be a way to do it directly, using the `"_id"` field, since ES insists on converting `"_id"` values to strings. But there is a way to work around it.

First I set up a simple index with a few docs as follows:

```
PUT /test_index
{
   "settings": {
      "number_of_shards": 1
   }
}

POST /test_index/_bulk
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"doc","_id":1}}
{"title":"first doc"}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"doc","_id":2}}
{"title":"second doc"}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"doc","_id":3}}
{"title":"third doc"}
```

Then I tried using a [max aggregation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-max-aggregation.html), but got an error, because the `"_id"`s are strings:

```
POST /test_index/_search?search_type=count
{
   "aggs": {
      "max_id": {
         "max": {
            "field": "_id"
         }
      }
   }
}
...
{
   "error": "SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed; shardFailures {[bQS7TqO9SfKSPQZYVXQBag][test_index][0]: ClassCastException[org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.plain.PagedBytesIndexFieldData cannot be cast to org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.IndexNumericFieldData]}]",
   "status": 500
}
```

So that doesn't work. But a slight modification does, using the `"path"` parameter in the [`"_id"` field](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-id-field.html).

So I redefine the index as

```
DELETE /test_index

PUT /test_index
{
   "settings": {
      "number_of_shards": 1
   },
   "mappings": {
      "doc": {
         "_id": {
            "path": "doc_id"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

and then index the docs using the `"doc_id"` path:

```
POST /test_index/_bulk
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"doc"}}
{"title":"first doc","doc_id":1}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"doc"}}
{"title":"second doc","doc_id":2}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"doc"}}
{"title":"third doc","doc_id":3}
```

Now if I search, I can see that `"_id"` is still a string, but `"doc_id"` is an integer:

```
POST /test_index/_search
...
{
   "took": 1,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 3,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "title": "first doc",
               "doc_id": 1
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "2",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "title": "second doc",
               "doc_id": 2
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "3",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "title": "third doc",
               "doc_id": 3
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

So now I can easily use the max aggregation to find the maximum id value:

```
POST /test_index/_search?search_type=count
{
   "aggs": {
      "max_id": {
         "max": {
            "field": "doc_id"
         }
      }
   }
}
...
{
   "took": 1,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 3,
      "max_score": 0,
      "hits": []
   },
   "aggregations": {
      "max_id": {
         "value": 3
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer.Now i am able to get max value.How should i used it in query for eg:-  select * from orders where deviceid > '(Max Id in Elastic search )' .How should i substitute value in " Max Id in Elastic search". Note : - river is scheduled to run every hour,hence very time river/query runs it should be able to get max value from elastic search

Comment: You will probably have to write some sort of script to handle that part. Maybe a python script run by a cron job or something.

Comment: How to give script as an input to parameter tab in jdbc river plugin ?

Comment: Nice but this seems to be deprecated (http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-id-field.html#_path). However "copy_to" instead of "path" should work.